# Eclipse: How do I refresh an entire workspace? F5 doesn't do it

Tags: eclipse, refresh, workspace

I have a workspace with a bunch of java projects. If I go to `File->Refresh`, it doesn't really refresh anything (perhaps the currently selected project). How do I get eclipse to refresh *all* of the projects?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212633/can-eclipse-refresh-resources-automatically/1212650#1212650

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It will indeed only refresh the current project (or, more specifically, the current selection in the project explorer). I just click somewhere in the project explorer, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all projects and then press <kbd>F5</kbd> to achieve a complete refresh.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but note that doing the above in the "Project Explorer" doesn't work (refresh is grayed out), but doing it in the "Package Explorer" it worked fine.

Comment: Problem with this is though, that if any of my projects are closed (which is all the time), the Refresh option does not appear.  The only way Ctrl+A followed by F5 works for me is if all my projects are open.

Comment: @Matt: My Project Explorer is configured to hide closed projects. They are only visible in Navigator. You might want to do the same.

Comment: I guess this is the only way? but it is not elegant. requires opening all projects.

Comment: @Trevor: no as BalusC said you can hide closed projects... again which is not always desirable..   What I ended up doing is actually set "Top Level Elements" to Working Sets which are never closed, so Ctrl+A always works... as well as keeping my workspace more organised..especially with the Dynamic Working Sets plugin(which means no maintenance after setting up some regexes).

Comment: @Matt: I get around this by doing Ctrl+A, then holding Ctrl left-click closed projects to exclude them. Then it works.

Comment: If you go the filter out closed project route, the instructions to do that are here http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcjviewfilters.html

Comment: Note that _ctrl-a_ does not always work in Project explorer, [bug 281966](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281966). Either select (all) items by ctrl/shift or select none, then press F5, as described in other answer(s).

Comment: This answer of selecting **all** projects in the explorer and hitting _F5_ seems strictly inferior to the answer by @blackburn below, of selecting **none**.  Because selecting none will work even if there are closed projects and it will also refresh the workspace itself.

Comment: You should collapse all projects in Project Explorer to be able to refresh them. If you have any uncollapsed project and then use `Ctrl + A` to select all, the refresh will be disappear.

Comment: This crashed my Eclipse.

Comment: 8 years later, I'm using Oxygen and this answer still holds. Thanks much!

Answer (score 43):

If you want to refresh *all* Projects, ignoring closed projects, then the easiest way is to:

- **ctrl-click** and item in the Project Explorer (to ensure the P. Explorer has focus)
- **ctrl-click** the item again so that it's no longer highlighted (but the P. Explorer still has focus)
- **F5** will now Refresh the entire workspace

Effectively F5 refreshes the Workspace when a navigation view has focus and nothing is selected.

Comment: This worked well for me on a Mac substituting cmd-click for ctrl-click

Comment: This is a great workaround for when you have many projects and folders (since ctrl-A right-click doesn't allow refresh if folders are selected)

Answer (score 16):

Ctrl-A, then F5.

You can set up the workspace to *automatically* refresh when it detects changes in the preferences. (Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh Automatically)

Answer (score 10):

Easy.

- Create an external tool: Run > External Tools > External Tools
  Configuration...
- Create a new Program configuration Point the location to an exe that is very fast (I use Cygwin's 'ls')
- On the Refresh tab, choose Refresh Resources upon completion, The Entire Workspace
- On the Build tab, deselect Build before launch

Run the tool to refresh all projects.

Comment: on windows i've used "C:\Windows\twunk_32.exe" 
doesn't seem to hurt :)

Comment: How can I know if the refresh is complete?

Comment: This is great!  I'm now able to type cmd-3 echo (because I used /bin/echo as the command) and immediately refresh, making it much less of a burden to skip the performance-wrecking autobuilds.  Because it gets a menu item, it could also go in a quicksilver trigger or similar setup, so it could be a global keystroke from outside eclipse.

Comment: This led me to something even simpler: cmd-3 build all.  (posting as an answer)

Comment: Apologizing for the noise: I've found I have to refresh first and then build.  Neither alone is sufficient.  (I'd mistakenly thought both actually, that refreshing triggered builds, and that building would start with a refresh.  Neither is true.)  I use an external tool config with a refresh hook first, and then cmd-3 build all.

Answer (score 6):

Control click all your projects together, then right click and hit refresh.

Usually I refresh all like that, then i make sure to clean all projects and rebuild in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone curious how to select all of those projects on OS X where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work:

1. Click the first project
2. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>
3. Hold the <kbd>↓</kbd> key until they are all selected
4. Now press <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: OS X's analogue of `Ctrl+A` is `⌘+A`, which does select all.

Comment: It works for me inconsistently (I sometimes have to click around the Project Explorer a few times first).

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15510230/411282) led me to an even simpler solution, no configuration necessary.

Cmd-3 build all (control-3 on windows)

**Edit:** Correction -- I need to *both* refresh *and* build.  Build does not automatically refresh.  I'm currently using two actions, "echo" from my comment in the linked answer I just referred to (an External Tool configuration with a hook to refresh all), followed by cmd-3 "build all"