# Android/Eclipse: how can I add an image in the res/drawable folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, resources

I am completely new with Android/Eclipse. I can't figure out how to add an image in the `/res/drawable` folder of my Android Eclipse project.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Copy the image <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> then in Eclipse select drawable folder, <kbd>right click</kbd> -> <kbd>Paste</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, it works... The drag and drop didn't work so that I though that copy/paste didn't work either!

Answer (score 28):

Drop in the image in /res/drawable folder. Then in Eclipse Menu, do ->Project -> Clean. This will do a clean build if set to build automatically.

Comment: The cleaning is normally a big deal. People need to remember that!

Answer (score 10):

Just copy the image and paste into Eclipse in the `res/drawable` directory. Note that the image name should be in lowercase, otherwise it will end up with an error.

Comment: Also, be careful that the image name is not a keyword, like do or for.

Comment: It also appears that it does not like hyphens.  I had fbc-logo.png and it would throw an error on paste.  renamed to fbclogo.png and good to go.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on drawable folder_new_file-
click on advanced button_
link to file in the file system_
then click on browse.
finish

Answer (score 3):

You can just put it in on the file system.  Eclipse will pick up the change on the next refresh.  Click the folder and press F5 to refresh.  BTW, make sure the file name does not have any capital letters... it will break android... and eclipse will let you know.

Comment: This was very essential

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the information .It helped me out as my project was somehow not visible in workspace therefore I had to insert the image from ECLIPSE IDE.
Also another way to do it is:
The image to be inserted should be copied ctrl+c and then right click on the drawable folder and PASTE it.
The image comes in drawable folder using ECLIPSE IDE.
You can use the image as an icon of the application using Manifest File-**android:icon="@drawable/image_name"**

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add an image from your computer? Just right click the folder in Eclipse and click Import

Comment: Yes, I want to import an image which is somewhere on my computer. The solution which works is a simple copy in the explorer and paste in eclipse. I didn't expect that it would work as the drag and drop directly in Eclipse didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

When inserting an image into the drawable folders, another import point in addition to the "no capital letters" rule is that the image name cannot contain dashes or other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Open folder path of Android application, open `src` folder then Add your image in `/res/drawable` folder

Answer (score 0):

For **Android Studio**:

1. Right click on res, new **Image Asset**
2. On **Asset type** choose **Action Bar and Tab Icons**
3. Choose the **image path**
4. Give your image a name in Resource name
5. Next->Finish

**The image will be saved in the /res/drawable folder!**

Answer (score -1):

You just need to copy/cut and paste the images into drawable folder using windows/mac file explorer

To refresh the workspace follow the steps mentioned in this question 
[Eclipse: How do i refresh an entire workspace? F5 doesn't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518428/eclipse-how-do-i-refresh-an-entire-workspace-f5-doesnt-do-it)

If that does not work you might wanna restart eclispe

Answer (score -1):

Try to use jpg and png , also name your image in lowercase. Then drag and drop the image in res/drawable . then go to file and click save all . close eclipse then reopen it again . That is what worked for me .