# android drawable recognise resources

Tags: android, drawable

I drag and drop an image into my "drawable" folder,

But I have to wait about 5 minutes to have eclipse recognise the newly added resource,

How can I update the resources that Eclipse recognises?,

before it does it automatically? [takes to long]

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don&t use the refresh button, it will take time for eclipse to recognize new added resources. Make sure to refresh.

Comment: For Eclipse look under "File"

Answer (score 1):

You can either `Refresh` your Esclipse, or `clean the Project`.

You can clean the project at `project` Tab,
and refresh at `File` tab.

I recommend cleaning your project each time you touch the dir folder =)

Take a look at this answer:

```
Eclipse: How do i refresh an entire workspace? F5 doesn't do it
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518466/1610949