# The compiler ignores increment operation

Tags: c++, increment

Why compiler ignores increment operation?
Version of gcc is 3.3.
IDE: Eclipde

Program code:

```
// File t.cc
#include <stdio.h> 
int main (void)
{
  int x = 1;
  x++; // ? 
  printf ("x=%d\n", x);  
  return 0;
}
```

Running the program:

```
$ g++ -ansi t.cc
x=1
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/l1jnyj). Are you sure that's the code you're compiling?

Comment: Did you run with "-ansi"?

Comment: Yes, with the same result.

Comment: @op so without `-ansi` you get the correct result?

Comment: Check [here](http://ideone.com/HoaHQV) a copy paste of your code, how is that different from what you get?

Comment: @dima what is ur IDE ?

Comment: @Pompei2 Version of gcc is 3.3

Comment: @if u replace `x++;  with   x+=1;` does it work ?

Comment: What is the rationale for using the `-ansi` flag? Additionally, why use `printf()` instead of `cout` in a C++ program? Finally, the gcc you are using is 'ancient'.

Comment: @dima, your problem is neither your code nor the compiler; it's most probably Eclipse.

Comment: @dima try to clean your project , and then build it again. (in Eclipse IDE) it helps to solve problems from that kind.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518428/eclipse-how-do-i-refresh-an-entire-workspace-f5-doesnt-do-it][1]

your eclipse project needs to be refresh.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518428/eclipse-how-do-i-refresh-an-entire-workspace-f5-doesnt-do-it

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this question. If you assume the compiler is at fault, posting the compiler version (and possibly the IDE you're using if it's relevant) is useful. Secondly, there's nothing wrong with the code sample. So one would naturally conclude that either your compiler installation is broken, or that whatever you're omitting from the question is at fault. **ECLIPSE IS NOT A COMPILER!**

Comment: To comment on the question-edit: the compiler is not ignoring anything. I suspect that (1) Eclipse is invoking `g++` by passing it  some cached entry, (2) Eclipse is invoking `g++` with the correct code but executes a stale binary, (3) Both. Have you tried wiping your 'workspace' and  installing 500 unrelated plugins? You should do the Eclipse dance until she is satisfied ;)

Comment: Have you tried the command line version of `g++` instead of Eclipse?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Yes, it's working. I think the problem is in Eclipse

Comment: @dima: the main problem *is* Eclipse..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code returns `x` value as 2. Re-compile & execute again.

[image]

Comment: would suggests to clean then rebuild and run  :)

Comment: @Yuva, it's tagged as C++ and compiled by invoking `g++`. This, combined with the `.cc` extension suggests he is just mixing in C which shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 10):

Your compiler is broken. A fix for this would be to get a new one.

Comment: hahahaha dude come on

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou it's a valid answer...

Comment: Well the answer is correct , the code showed above in OP question should be compiled in any compiler as expected.

Comment: More likely OP's not actually compiling the code in the question, but a subtly broken variant of it.

Comment: indeed I have a feeling he trying this `printf ("x=%d\n", x++);`
which will increment the `x` after the `printf`.

Comment: @Roma-MT No, the code is correct