# selenium jar files show as missing in project build path

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAlEa.png)Adding jar files from the latest version of selenium 3.141.59 show missing after adding them inside the build path of my project.

Windows 10, Eclipse, selenium 3.141.59

the client- combined files shouldn't be missing. previously it worked out.

[image: Directory]

Comment: Can you refresh your eclipse project, it's possible it's not picking up the changes made in directory. See: [this SO question about refreshing eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518428/eclipse-how-do-i-refresh-an-entire-workspace-f5-doesnt-do-it)

Comment: web driver java 3.141.59 only 5 jars 5 are missing i have the same scenario so i dont know how to find another 5 i guess that we need to try again with the previous bersion

Comment: hello, lately it worked out with by cleaning projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **Selenium Java Client** in addition to adding **`client-combined-3.141.59.jar`** with the build path of your project you also have to add the following *jars* from the **libs** sub-directory:

- **`byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar`**
- **`commons-exec-1.3.jar`**
- **`guava-25.0-jre.jar`**
- **`okhttp-3.11.0.jar`**
- **`okio-1.14.0.jar`**

Snapshot of **libs** sub-directory:

[image: Selenium_libs_directory]

Comment: Please have a look in my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing/Updating as `@Rakib` mentioned in comments might work.

However, I would suggest having some Build Tools such as Ant, Maven or Gradle in place for Dependency Management. This would automatically resolve and import the required jar files.

The current format of handling jar files would be confined to local and if you try to export the project into a different operating system that would throw an error defining missing jar files.

Answer (score 0):

I have added all the jar files but still showing error for particular client combined jar files. show as corrupted. However I managed to download it from the following link: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k15UT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use maven. It is very easy to maintain java projects with it. In case you are missing something, you can easily add dependency, or in case everything is on your project, but not on your local machine, you will just need to refresh your dependencies and maven will do the rest. here is the link: http://maven.apache.org/