# Refresh eclipse projects via command line

Tags: eclipse, command-line, batch-file

How to refresh eclipse projects via command line?

(an equivalent of *right-click > refresh* in package view)
I need to refresh eclipse from a batch after a maven nightly build.

Comment: Check this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6049245/207764
Refreshing from commandline, do you mean when you are starting up Eclipse? Or if you have an eclipse open already?

Comment: @Fredrik: I mean when I have an eclipse open already, but I'm interested in both.

Comment: @Fredrik: Question stackoverflow.com/a/6049245/207764 is not from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know there are ant tasks to do this:

```xml
<eclipse.convertPath fileSystemPath="/workspace/org.example.project"
                     property="resourcePath"/>
<eclipse.refreshLocal resource="${resourcePath}" depth="infinite"/>
```

As for running this from the command line, as a worst case, you can stick this in an ant script invoke the eclipse antrunner application:

> eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -f
>   refresh.xml

Comment: I've got an error: BUILD FAILED
C:\...\refresh.xml:2: Unexpected element "{}eclipse.convertPath" {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}eclipse.convertPath

Comment: I also got it, how do I fix it? btw, I am in linux if that matters something