# Having issues with android manifest files

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have the following AndroidManifest file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.obviam.droidz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/images"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".HomeView" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DroidzActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GameOver">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am getting the following compilation error, which I can't seem to figure out...

```
    [2012-04-17 08:39:23 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /home/joshua/workspace/Droidz/AndroidManifest.xml: Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Could anyone please suggest the cause of the error.

Comment: no, there was end manifest tag(but formatting was bad)

Comment: I know this question may be silly, but when I create a new Android project in Eclipse, the first java class that is created if filled with the "Activity" name. I usually use that java class as my Main activity, so I was wondering if your HomeView is really your main activity: from that activity you access to the other sub-activities?

Comment: I've checked your manifest. No error in manifest.

Comment: it is a proper manifest i guess.

Comment: V4I3ri4, that is correct. I changed my first activity later on after I created a main menu.

Comment: Are you getting any other errors besides that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest file should end with

```
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Still unsure as to what happened, but it appears the formatting was not the problem. After restarting eclipse, the issues went away. Sorry to have bothered you all, thank you for your help though.

Comment: Same issue here.  Closed and re-opened and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

When something like this problem happens in Eclipse, it can help to refresh and rebuild the project. Eclipse from version 3.7 can handle auto-refresh https://stackoverflow.com/a/6049245.

Comment: Refresh / Clean did not help.  I'm using version 4.2.0 of Eclipse.