# eclipse, refresh files edited by external editor

Tags: eclipse, refresh, external

I currently use emacs to edit .java files and run eclipse.

Eclipse doesn't automatically recognize modified files, so I often end up running unmodified application.

I wonder if there exists a shortcut to refresh all the modified files in eclipse.

Comment: Same here with SCSS files using Notepad++ to edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Eclipse refresh resources automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212633/can-eclipse-refresh-resources-automatically)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Perhaps you want to check `Preferences > General > Workspaces > Refresh using native hooks or polling`. You can see that the eclipse refreshes the file you edit with external editor (like vi, emacs, etc) when you check the option.

Comment: Window (on top in menu bar in Eclipse)->Preferences->General->Workspaces(click on Workspaces)->On right there is a check-box titled 'Refresh using native hooks or polling', checkmark it, click APPLY and OK.

Comment: Also, I had to check the "Build automatically" option.

Answer (score 3):

On the project explorer you need to select the project(s) that you want to refresh and then click on File->Refresh or hit F5.