# Setting up hot deployment with eclipse and Jboss

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I am used to work with rails locally where I can use any text editor I please while I have the server running. If I make changes to a file Webrick, it will pick it up and I am able to see the changes on the page.

Can I do this with eclipse? 
I am using Atom for html editing but every time I save the changes and reload the page, the changes are not done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer by going to eclipse in `Preferences > General > Workspaces > Refresh using native hooks or polling`

This way I am able to edit html files with Atom. Hope it helps someone

Question for reference: [eclipse, refresh files edited by external editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470311/eclipse-refresh-files-edited-by-external-editor)

Answer (score 0):

Is your project an Eclipse Web project associated with a server in the Eclipse `Servers` view? If so, double-click on the server and you'll be able to tweak a few thing. The interesting option would be `Automatically publish when resources change` under `Publishing`.

PS: if you're using Java Enterprise or JBoss technologies, you can add [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/) on top of your Eclipse IDE, it features some features and default settings that should make things simpler for you.

Comment: It is already checked. To be a little more clear I change something on Atom, save it, go back to eclipse, and it picks up the changes BUT I have to do ctrl+s in eclipse too so that jboss (or eclipse) will reflect those changes in the browser.  @Mickael