# What are the things should be considered while using git using console while developement using IDE(Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am very new to `Git` perhaps I don't like eclipse's git plugin. So I prefer to use git using Linux terminal.
So consider I am creating a branch using the terminal

```
git branch test
git checkout test
```

And I am typing the code in a file without refreshing the `eclipse` java project will my changes reflect in that branch.

Also let me know the exceptional cases one should consider while using git with `eclipse`.

Comment: Perhaps check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470311/eclipse-refresh-files-edited-by-external-editor for information about keeping eclipse in sync with the filesystem. Also, if you're looking for a GUI git client, I'd recommend the great (imo) GitKraken: https://www.gitkraken.com/ . Beautiful, friendly, cross-platform.

Comment: I don't like GUI clients, prefer terminal because I can find it on any machine. still thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a whole lot. The big ones are to make sure that the local clone is known to Eclipse by adding it to the **Git Repositories** View, and that the *Automatic refresh* options on the main **Git** preference page and *Refresh using native hooks or polling* on the **Workspace** preference page are enabled.

There's nothing wrong with using the `git` command for your work and having *eGit* installed just to make modifications and branch information more immediately visible in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and commit the changes by `git add` and `git commit` command so that they get reflected in your current working branch. See documentation here :

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Also, to create a new branch 'test' and checkout it, you can use:

`git checkout -b test`

rather than :

```
git branch test
git checkout test
```

Since you are very new to Git, I would suggest you to go through this tuorial: https://try.github.io/

Comment: I know the basic concepts, what I am mean to say here is after doing all those things i.e `add commit branch` from git console, If I *don't refresh* eclipse project will it keep writing on master branch? or on test branch.