# Why do only some of the subprojects of a maven project refresh when changing SVN branches in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

I have a maven project with several subprojects. When I change branches only some of the subprojects indicate that the code is pointing to the newly switched to branch in the navigator window.  Has anyone else seen this?  Why does it only happen some of the time?  Is there a way I can get all of the subprojects to update correctly (I've tried switching using "Working Copy" and "Fully Recursive" and I've also tried doing a refresh on all of the subprojects as well as team->refresh/clean up followed by refresh)?

Comment: Might be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470311/eclipse-refresh-files-edited-by-external-editor

Comment: The display doesn't change even if I manually refresh all of the subprojects.

Comment: Have you tried to look into eclipse log?