# Java App Engine Standard Environment server caching static resources

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I switched from the Google App Engine plugin to Google Cloud SDK plugin with Java app engine components.

Now when I run the server from Eclipse, it copies all the files for my web application into a temporary directory inside .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1

When I modify a JS file on the file system they are not automatically published to the temp1 folder, so when I refresh the browser, it loads the old version of the JS file.

With the old Google App Engine plugin I would modify a JS file and refresh the browser and it would instantly load the changes.

Is there some setting I need to modify to get it to work the way I want it to?

I found a file in workspace/Server/App Engine Standard at localhost.server. But I'm not sure what auto-publish-setting means.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<server auto-publish-setting="2" auto-publish-time="0" hostname="localhost" id="App Engine Standard at localhost" name="App Engine Standard at localhost" runtime-id="App Engine Standard Runtime" server-type="com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.standard.server" server-type-id="com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.standard.server" start-timeout="240" stop-timeout="240" timestamp="12">
  <list key="app-engine-server-modules-list" value0="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CodeAvengers"/>
  <list key="modules" value0="CodeAvengers::org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CodeAvengers::jst.web::3.1"/>
</server>
```

Here are the settings for static files in `appengine-web.xml`

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/js/**" expiration="1s" />
    <include path="/i/**" expiration="1s" />
    <include path="/audio/**" expiration="1s" />
    <include path="/image/**" expiration="1s" />
    <include path="/images/**" expiration="1s" />
    <include path="/css/**" expiration="1s" />
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="1s"/>
    <include path="/d-md/**" expiration="1s" />
    <include path="**" expiration="30d"/>

    <exclude path="/d/**" />
    <exclude path="/ca/**" />
    <exclude path="/files/**" />
</static-files>
```

With the old Google App Engine eclipse plugin, these settings worked totally fine.

I checked the temp1 folder and it seems the auto republishing is not working. When I modify a file in the source folder, those changes are not getting auto published.

Is there some setting somewhere else that is overriding the auto publish setting?

Answer (score 1):

The auto-publish-setting="2" is a Eclipse setting that you modify when you right click on the server and select 'open'. Go to the 'Publishing' category on the right. There are three options, each corresponds to a number. The number 2 corresponds to 'Automatically publish when resources change'. See image below:

[image]

If you want to see changes in the static files, you should set a low expiration attribute to the file in the appengine-web.xml. It would be something like:

```
<static-files>
  <include path="/**.png" expiration="4d 5h" />
</static-files>
```

In the example above you can use s for seconds. See the [appengine-web.xml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) especially the `<static-files>` and the [static cache expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#static_cache_expiration) section, for a list of configuration options.

On the other hand, if you use a high expiration attribute, you won't see the changes immediately. As [this section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#static_cache_expiration) explains:

".. After a file is transmitted with a given expiration time, there is generally no way to clear it out of intermediate caches, even if the user clears their own browser cache. Re-deploying a new version of the app will not reset any caches..."

Comment: I've updated my question to show my settings for static files in app-engine.xml. These settings worked fine with the old "Google App Engine" plugin.

Comment: What is the situation now ? Did a combination of the Eclipse settitng + the expiration attribute work ?

Comment: Thanks for the response!! I already had both of those set. I just updated my answer. The problem seems to be that the auto publishing is not working. I am assuming it is supposed to copy over changes from my source folder into the temp1 directory. When I refresh my browser is loads the version from the temp1 folder.  At once stage I did see an error message about difficulties copying over to the temp1 folder. I'll try restarting eclipse in admin mode and see if that fixes the auto publishing.

Comment: Try in **Window > Preferences > Server > Launching** see [this doc](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwsrtins.html)

Comment: I tried that... it is still not working. When I restart the server, all the changes get copied/published from the source directory into the temporary directory. But any changes made once the server is running, are not being auto published.

Comment: I tried creating a new blank app engine project, and the auto publishing worked ok with the new project. With my old project, it is not working. I might try creating a new project, and copy across all the old files, and see if that has any effect.

Comment: Ok. You can try on a file by file basis until you see when the problem appears.

Comment: OK. Have some more details now. I created a new app engine project in eclipse, then added a JS file. When I update the file in Eclipse the JS file is auto republished. When I update the JS file in a text editor outside of Eclipse, the auto publishing doesn't happen.

Comment: I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470311/eclipse-refresh-files-edited-by-external-editor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161271/discussion-between-victor-herasme-perez-and-mike).

Comment: The refresh with native hooks option worked well with a small application but was still quite slow with my application which has a lot of files. It takes a few seconds to update.