# Is there a way to ge Eclipse to not refresh workspace when its in background?

Tags: eclipse

It seems that Eclipse detects file changes and does a workspace refresh even when its not in the foreground (top window). Is there a way to turn that off so it waits until its in the foreground again to do the workspace refresh, essentially queuing up the changes until I activate it again?

Basically I don't want it taking up CPU trying to rebuild the workspace while I am making changes in other tools. The main case where I see this a lot is when I am doing a git rebase from the command line. While the rebase is running Eclipse keeps rebuilding the workspace based on the ongoing changes.

Note I do want it to refresh when I activate again. Essentially I want the refresh to work like IntelliJ.

For reference, here is a good set of answers on how Eclipse workspace refresh works - [Can Eclipse refresh resources automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212633/can-eclipse-refresh-resources-automatically)

Note refreshing the workspace can even cause problems in Eclipse at which point it raises an error dialog and brings itself to the foreground.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could uncheck the "Bild automatically" option for the project. For performance reasons it US also advisable to close all projects that are not currently needed, and use different workspaces for each project.

Comment: Per my question, I still want it to build when I activate Eclipse again (like IntelliJ does).

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing automatically and Building automatically are not the same thing.  There isn't a way to do exactly what you want, but Building automatically while not Refreshing automatically is probably the closest thing.  Manually triggering a Refresh will then cause automatic building to occur on those changes.