# Refresh Eclipse project on file save in Atom

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I am using Eclipse *(Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2))* because I have to (my team uses it for SVN purposes) and I am editing the CSS and .jsp files in Atom (the Github's text editor). Whenever I change and save a file in Atom I have to go and manually refresh the project in Eclipse for changes to appear. This is very time-consuming and I am not sure if I can fix this.

I have tried both refresh on access and refresh via native hooks ...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest Atom with Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) and Tomcat as the web container. Setting both

General -> Workspace -> Refresh using native hooks or pooling
and
General -> Workspace -> Refresh on access

works for me. It is described at [Can Eclipse refresh resources automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212633/can-eclipse-refresh-resources-automatically).