# Getting HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java, tomcat

I Created a Dynamic web project where the input parameters are coming from UI(Index.html) going to `servlet.java`, but when I am trying to call auth in `oAuthBean.java` file its giving me an error.

Attached navigation view:

[image]

Exception:

```
Aug 24, 2017 3:18:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [clientCredServlet1] in context with path [/Java-Credit-Offers-Example] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at controller.clientCredServlet.doPost(clientCredServlet.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We can only help if you provide us with more information such as the code and project configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your servlet uses Apache http client (that's where `org.apache.http.HttpEntity` is coming from), but corresponding dependency jar is not present in resulting deployment, most likely because there is a lack of configuration glue between Maven and Eclipse WTP plugin which deploys to and runs your Tomcat from IDE. That lack appeared because it seems that Maven project has been created outside of Eclipse.

### Option 1. Leave things as is and do quickfix (worse)

Try executing under your project root folder:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

and reopen Eclipse workspace then

According to [Maven Eclipse plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/wtp.html) when the `wtpversion` flag is explicitly set, maven generates necessary workspace configuration for WTP plugins (including Tomcat one) in order to let them understand how to obtain Maven dependencies during deployments from Eclipse

### Option 2. Rely on built-in IDE integration with Maven (best for long term)

Examine [following great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064664/8513835) which, at some approximation, describes why, and how to rely on **built-in** Eclipse Maven support. This approach eliminates the problem with missing dependencies in IDE deployments as well, but requires more effort to migrate project onto, which however is quite minor while your project is at the beginning stage