# Spring Boot + Eclipse : why application.properties is excluded in .classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I created a basic SpringBoot 1.5.7 app from http://start.spring.io/ (Java, Maven), and I'm working with the Eclipse project created with `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

I noticed that if I modify my `application.properties` file and afterwards run a Junit test (all from inside Eclipse), the new version is not used.

Digging a little, I found that the new `application.properties` file is not copied from `src/main/resources/` to `target/classes/` by the Eclipse build. And it seems that the cause is that it's marked as "excluded" in the Eclipse project settings. Indeed, my (automatically generated) `.classpath` file says:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" 
     including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" 
excluding="**/*.java|**/application*.yml|**/application*.yaml|**/application*.properties"/>
  ...
```

Of course, the file is actually copied when I run the Maven `spring-boot:run` target.

Why, then, is it excluded by Eclipse's classpath? Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is quite broken. It's better to not rely on it, simply [import as Maven Project from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064664/277304) and be happy.

Comment: Even though i imported as "Maven Project" the issue still exist. If anybody using eclipse go to "Build path" and edit "src/main/resources" to include instead of excluding. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can not tell you why, but I can tell you how to fix it :)

You need to change your configuration so that it does not filter the resource folder, such as:

```
<build>
        <resources>
             <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>scheduler</finalName>
                </configuration>
                 <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This overwrites the default behaviour that I assume to be implemented in the parent pom. I will double check and raise it with the boot-guys.

Thanks,

Artur

Comment: Did you ever get an answer from the "boot-guys"?

Comment: To be honest, I forgot. I think it might have to do with the fact that the maven eclipse plugin is retired. Filtering is turned on, yes, but properties are included by default, see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml. I forgot to raise it, but I somewhat imagine that that won't be fruitful. Have you tried the eclipse m2e maven plugin (the pom is setup for that). I use the eclipse plugin from the command line.