# Can I refresh Eclipse Project Explorer automatically?

Tags: eclipse

Can I refresh the explorer without pressing F5 button? I want it keep refresh by itself while running the project.

I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Eclipse refresh resources automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212633/can-eclipse-refresh-resources-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

From eclipse doc [Workspace](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-9.htm)

Select Check Box: **Refresh using native hooks or polling**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is needed to check both "Refresh using native hooks or polling" and "Refresh On Access".
But not only check the "Refresh On Access".

Answer (score 0):

there's a new preference Settings > General > Workspace > Refresh On Access (aka Lightweight Refresh). This preference causes Eclipse to automatically refresh resources when it discovers that they're 'out-of-sync'. When opening, reading or searching files, it'll prevent out-of-sync errors from occurring.

Other option is preference Settings > General > Workspace >Refresh using native hooks or polling

If this option is turned on then the workspace resources will be synchronized with their corresponding resources in the file system automatically using native refresh providers (on Windows) or a polling mechanism.

**Note**: This can potentially be a lengthy operation depending on the number of resources you have in your workspace.

For more details 
[Can Eclipse refresh resources automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212633/can-eclipse-refresh-resources-automatically?rq=1)

Comment: I found that. It is needed to check both "Refresh using native hooks or polling" and "Refresh On Access". But not only check the "Refresh On Access".